# C cant print first letter of LPVOID ( expression must be a pointer to a complete object type)

Tags: c, winapi

I wrote a code that has an `LPVOID` variable and I want to print the first letter of the buffer that variable points to; however I get the error:

> expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Can someone show me how can I do it right?

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char letterZ[] = "Z";
    LPVOID buffer;
    HANDLE hFile;

    hFile = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE, TRUE, "sourceFile");
    if (hFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("can't open the mapped file.\n");
        _exit(1);
    }

    buffer = MapViewOfFile(hFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("can't map view of file.\n");
        _exit(1);
    }
    printf("buffer first letter: %c", (char)buffer[0]); // here I try to print and get the error
    snprintf((char*)buffer, sizeof(letterZ), letterZ);

    UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: the code write in c but ok.

Comment: You should convert LPVOID (void*) to char* and dereference the first character: `printf("buffer first letter: %c", *((char*)buffer));`

Comment: @רועיאטיאס: You can ask for either C or C++. If you want to ask for an answer in C, remove `#include <iostream>` and anything else that is not C, delete the C++ tag, and add the C tag. Please do not ask for both at the same time. Different sets of people follow the C and C++ tags, and some of them do not want to expend their time on the tag they are not following.

Comment: I retagged for C as this is obviously C code. Not sure why it was changed to C++.

Comment: @siride: It is not obviously C code, and the tags were not changed to C++. The original title stated C++, the original tags were C and C++, and the code contains `#include <iostream>`, which will not work in C. OP needs to pick one and make the title, the code, and the tags consistent.

Comment: The only reason you could say it is C++ is that mistaken iostream import. The rest of the code is bog standard C: stdio, printf, pointers. There's nothing in here that looks like C++. No classes, references, templates, use of C++ headers (not just accidental inclusion). What value would this be in the C++ tag?

Comment: @siride the value would be that the language tag was the language of the code in the question

Comment: Cast the pointer to point to char and the dereference that char*

Comment: Yes, which is why it should be tagged as C. The OP also confirmed it.

Comment: buffer[0] cannot be resolved by a compiler since buffer here is a pointer to "anything" (void). void pointers are basically used only to be passed around, but they cannot by use to access the memory that's behind. You must first cast it to a non void pointer, like char*. Then you'll be able to access the char(s) behind.

Comment: @siride the code in the question is C++ because of istream

Comment: @siride: Re “The only reason”: First, I cited three reasons: the title, the code, and the tags. Second, a reason is a reason. A C compiler will not compile `#include <iostream>` barring abnormal intervention. A wrong tag is a wrong tag. OP can edit the question to make it consistent. We do not always know where a question will lead. It should be clarified.

Comment: The author changed the title from saying "C++" to saying "C" and has stated in the comments that the code is C. That leaves the extraneous `#include` unaddressed. I think that's enough to justify helping the author fully convert the question to C.

Comment: @JaMiT Fair comment - I've edited my answer and I see you have tidied up the tags.

Comment: @JaMiT: Did you change the compiler they are using?

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, I did not change someone's compiler. What I changed was the question. I changed it to match what the author said the intent was. Whether or not the intent accurately reflects the author's situation is not my concern. Unlike many low-rep people, this asker actually responded to (a variant of asking) "C or C++?", so let's go with the stated intent, and help the question instead of hindering it.

Comment: @JaMiT: And here is the problem with that: If somebody says they are writing C code but they compile it with a C++ compiler, it is C++ code. Maybe we did not encounter any problems due to that in this particular question, but it is not correct to use C rules for code compiled in C++. The grammar of the conditional operator is different. The aliasing rules are different. Other rules are different. Instead of helping OP understand the issues and the differences and why they need to know which language they are really compiling in, you removed code that indicates they are indeed using C++, not C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While that argument is mostly right, it is also largely irrelevant. From the [tour]: *"we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."* The goal is high-quality answers and questions. There's no mention of "we'll make sure you ask the right question for your particular situation." We try, because that is being friendly and helpful, but once the author has clarified their intent, we're stuck with what was stated. All that's left is to get the question into answerable shape, and answer. Too bad if it doesn't help.

Comment: @JaMiT I've rolled back the edit to the OP's code because we don't do that.

Comment: OK, we don't edit code. We just tell someone else to do it, with no explanation, expecting them to blindly follow orders. But our hands are clean because we didn't do it? Right... This is a good system for driving away newcomers. Give them what they'll perceive as senseless hoops to jump through, so they'll buzz off instead of improving their question. *I would feel more charitable towards the commenters if the order to remove `<iostream>` explained that it is a C++ header, and explained why no one else can make this change, despite it being (to us) clearly extraneous to the stated question.*

Comment: @JaMiT: It is not senseless; it clarifies the issue, and I have seen plenty of times when people interpreted a question incorrectly. OP was not told to edit the code without explanation. And, in spite of the OP saying it is C code, the fact they are working with Microsoft Windows code means they are more likely than not compiling it with C++, even without considering `<iostream>`. It is not an arduous demand to have them clarify what language they are actually using. And, if they are mistaken about it and think that C code in a C++ compiler is C code, we can help them understand it is not.

Comment: I wrote *"they'll perceive as senseless"*; @EricPostpischil wrote *"It is not senseless"*. These statements are not contradictory. I intentionally used the word "perceive" because perceptions do not have to match reality, especially when dealing with someone (the OP) who demonstrated not understanding the distinction between C and C++. Compare the earlier comment to: *You can ask for either C or C++. However, `<iostream>` is a C++ header, so if you want to ask for an answer in C, you should remove that header, confirm that the example still reproduces the issue, and update your question.*

Answer (score 3):

Note: I have edited this answer to use *only* C language syntax and references. If required, I can rollback to include both the C and C++ 'versions' of the answer.

---

You can't dereference a `void*` pointer<sup>1</sup> (as `LPVOID` is), nor can you apply pointer arithmetic to it, as you have attempted to do in the `(char)buffer[0]` expression: Syntactically, the subscript operator (`[]`) applied to a pointer both applies arithmetic to *and* dereferences the pointer; [from cppreference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the
> expression `*(E1 + E2)` …

You can fix this in a number of ways, the simplest of which is to declare the `buffer` variable as a `char*` rather than as an `LPVOID`. Furthermore, using the `char*` type for `buffer` removes the need for the other casts that you have used elsewhere in your code.

Also, you have omitted the *required* `format` argument (which, presumably, should be `%s`) in your call to `snprintf`, and you should remove the `#include <iostream>` line, which is only usable in C++ source code.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char letterZ[] = "Z";
    char* buffer; // Use a char* rather than a void* (LPVOID)...
    HANDLE hFile;

    hFile = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE, TRUE, "sourceFile");
    if (hFile == NULL) {
        printf("can't open the mapped file.\n");
        _exit(1);
    }

    buffer = MapViewOfFile(hFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("can't map view of file.\n");
        _exit(1);
    }
    printf("buffer first letter: %c", buffer[0]); // Now works!
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(letterZ), "%s", letterZ); // Note the corrections in the arguments!

    UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> To explain the "incomplete type" part of the error message, here's a quote from a [C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.2.5 Types
>
> 19     The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.